# How to scroll the image based on their respective ids

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I have created a slider that displays content alongside respective images. I have successfully achieved this, but I am encountering an issue. For example, when I navigate to the 5th image using the buttons, the content for the 5th image is displayed correctly, but the 5th image itself does not scroll horizontally. I am unsure how to implement this horizontal scrolling. Any good solution would be greatly appreciated.

And Solution for scroll using trackpad gesture also if possible link me any articles or videos
Here's the code (Using React, TailwindCss, Framer Motion and React-icons)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react"
import { motion } from "framer-motion"
import { FaChevronRight as Right, FaChevronLeft as Left } from "react-icons/fa"
import images from "../images"

const Carousel = ({ images }) => {
  const carousel = useRef()
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const carouselWidth = carousel.current.scrollWidth
    const carouselOffset = carousel.current.offsetWidth
    setWidth(carouselWidth - carouselOffset)
  }, [])

  const handleImageClick = (image, index) => {
    setCurrentIndex(index)
  }

  const handleNavClick = direction => {
    if (direction === "prev" && currentIndex > 0) {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex - 1)
    } else if (direction === "next" && currentIndex < images.length - 1) {
      setCurrentIndex(currentIndex + 1)
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="carousel-container">
      <div
        style={{
          width: `${window.outerWidth}px`,
        }}
        ref={carousel}
        className="carousel mx-auto rounded-md overflow-hidden"
      >
        <motion.div
          drag="x"
          dragConstraints={{
            right: 0,
            left: -width,
          }}
          className="inner-carousel flex items-center ease-linear gap-4"
        >
          {images.map((image, idx) => (
            <div
              key={idx}
              onClick={() => handleImageClick(image, idx)}
              className={`min-w-[20rem] object-contain rounded-md h-[20rem] ${
                currentIndex === idx ? "border-4 border-red-600" : "opacity-50"
              }`}
            >
              <img
                src={image.url}
                alt=""
                className="pointer-events-none object-fit rounded-md"
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </motion.div>
      </div>
      <div className="carousel-content bg-green-300 px-16 relative">
        <div className="head">
          <h1 className="transition-all text-left ease-linear text-2xl font-bold">
            {images[currentIndex].title}
          </h1>
          <p className="transition-all text-justify ease-linear">
            {images[currentIndex].content}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="carousel-nav absolute top-4 transform translate-y-10 flex z-30 space-x-4">
          <button
            onClick={() => handleNavClick("prev")}
            className={`bg-red-600 text-white rounded-full p-2 ${
              currentIndex === 0 ? "opacity-50" : ""
            }`}
          >
            <Left />
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => handleNavClick("next")}
            className={`bg-red-600 text-white rounded-full p-2 ${
              currentIndex === images.length - 1 ? "opacity-50" : ""
            }`}
          >
            <Right />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const NetflixSlider = () => {
  return (
    <section className="netflix-slider h-screen ">
      <div className="container max-w-7xl overflow-hidden px-8 h-full py-4">
        <Carousel images={images} />
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default NetflixSlider
```

I tried to use drag feature of motion I couldn't achieve